# Excel-to-JSON parser

Tags: c#, parsing, json, excel

I just wanted to build a simple converter from an XLS Excel file to JSON. I have predefined JSON format. All fields except of two - are just simple mapping from Excel to JSON. The two fields have a special format, "|" separated values which should be converted to array items. I also need a geocode address and save latitude and longitude to corresponding fields.

```
  static class Program
{
    private static GoogleGeocoder GoogleGeocoder { get; set; }

    private static SettingsModel Settings { get; set; }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var cc = new ConsoleCopy("log.txt"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("--- starting convert XLS data to export.json "+DateTime.Now);

            GoogleGeocoder = new GoogleGeocoder(); // default api key used

            LoadSettings(@"settings.json");
            var result = ConvertExcelToJson();
            File.WriteAllText(@"export.json", result);

            Console.WriteLine("--- converting finished. Press any key to exit");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    private static void LoadSettings(string settingsFileName)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!File.Exists(settingsFileName))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("--- settings file was not found...");
                File.WriteAllText(settingsFileName, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new SettingsModel(true), Formatting.Indented));
                Console.WriteLine("--- settings file was created, please edit it and start the programm again...");
                Console.ReadKey();
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }

            Settings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SettingsModel>(File.ReadAllText(settingsFileName));

            Console.WriteLine("--- reading settings finished");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            HandleAndThrowException(ex, "Cannot open/read settings file. Please check if all settings are correct", false);
            Console.ReadKey();
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
    }

    private static string ConvertExcelToJson()
    {
        try
        {
            var nameField = Settings.FieldsMapping.Single(n => n.DestinationFieldName.Equals("Name")).SourceFieldNumber;
            var datesField = Settings.FieldsMapping.Single(n => n.DestinationFieldName.Equals("Dates")).SourceFieldNumber;
            var timesField = Settings.FieldsMapping.Single(n => n.DestinationFieldName.Equals("Times")).SourceFieldNumber;
            var zipField = Settings.FieldsMapping.Single(n => n.DestinationFieldName.Equals("PostsalCode")).SourceFieldNumber;
            var cityField = Settings.FieldsMapping.Single(n => n.DestinationFieldName.Equals("City")).SourceFieldNumber;
            var streetField = Settings.FieldsMapping.Single(n => n.DestinationFieldName.Equals("Street")).SourceFieldNumber;

            var book = new LinqToExcel.ExcelQueryFactory(Settings.FileName);

            var worksheetName = book.GetWorksheetNames().FirstOrDefault();
            if (worksheetName == null)
                throw new Exception("--- cannot find any worksheet");

            Console.Write("--- start converting [");

            var test = book
                .WorksheetRange(Settings.CellToStart, Settings.CellToEnd, worksheetName)
                .AsEnumerable()
                .Select(item =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        return new ExportsModel
                        {
                            Name = item[nameField].Cast<string>(),
                            ActionDates =
                                GetActionDatesArray(item[datesField].Cast<string>(), item[timesField].Cast<string>()),
                            City = item[cityField].Cast<string>(),
                            Geocode =
                                GetCoordinates(item[zipField].Cast<string>(), item[cityField].Cast<string>(),
                                    item[streetField].Cast<string>()),
                            Street = item[streetField].Cast<string>(),
                            PostalCode = item[zipField].Cast<string>(),
                            LastDate = GetLastDate(item[datesField].Cast<string>())
                        };
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                })
                .Where(obj => obj != null)
                .ToJSON();

            Console.WriteLine("]");

            return test;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            HandleAndThrowException(ex, "Cannot convert data. Please check if all settings are correct", false);
            return "";
        }
    }


    private static DateTime? GetLastDate(string dates)
    {
        try
        {
            return DateTime.Parse(dates.Split('|').Select(n => n.Trim()).LastOrDefault()).AddHours(23).AddMinutes(59);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            HandleAndThrowException(ex, "Cannot parse last date field. Value of the field: "+dates);
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<ActionDate> GetActionDatesArray(string dates, string times)
    {
        List<string> timesArray;
        List<string> datesArray;

        try
        {
            timesArray = times.Split('|').Select(n => n.Trim()).ToList();
            datesArray = dates.Split('|').Select(n => n.Trim()).ToList();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            timesArray = new List<string>();
            datesArray = new List<string>();
            HandleAndThrowException(ex, String.Format("Cannot parse date or time field. Values needed to parse: dates={0}, times={1}", dates, times));
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < datesArray.Count(); i++)
        {
            yield return new ActionDate()
            {
                Label = datesArray[i] + " " + timesArray[i] + "Uhr",
                Date = DateTime.Parse(datesArray[i]).AddHours(23).AddMinutes(59)
            };
        }
    }

    private static Geocode GetCoordinates(string zip, string city, string street)
    {
        try
        {
            IEnumerable<Address> addresses = GoogleGeocoder.Geocode(zip + " " + city + " " + street).ToList();
            var a = addresses.First().Coordinates.Latitude;

            Console.Write('.');

            return new Geocode()
            {
                Lat = addresses.First().Coordinates.Latitude,
                Lon = addresses.First().Coordinates.Longitude
            };

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // try again 
            try
            {
                return GetCoordinates(zip, city, street);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                HandleAndThrowException(ex, String.Format("The following data cannot be geocoded: ({0}-{1}-{2})", zip, city, street));
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void HandleAndThrowException(Exception ex, string customMessage, bool throwNewException = true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("*****************");
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("->");
        Console.WriteLine(customMessage);
        Console.WriteLine("*****************");

        if (throwNewException)
            throw new Exception("The shop will not be added to list", ex);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nearly 200 lines of code in one `Program` class is IMHO too much. To me, the `Program` class of a Console application should contain as little as possible, and all logic should be contained in separate, well-defined classes. Think [SOLID](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/703634/SOLID-architecture-principles-using-simple-Csharp).

I'd refactor `LoadSettings` and `ConvertExcelToJson` to a class each, for instance.

---

Consider not tying your feedback code logic to the Console. Instead implement something like [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/) to handle all your logging; this still allows you to output to the console. Using `ConsoleCopy` is a really hacky solution.

---

`Settings.FieldsMapping.Single(n => n.DestinationFieldName.Equals("Name")).SourceFieldNumber;` is repeated more than a dozen times, so instead of copy-pasting it and changing one string variable, move it to a method.

---

`ConvertExcelToJson` does a lot of things. Consider splitting it up into smaller methods, each handling a specific task. Of course, first you need to convert `ConvertExcelToJson` to a class of its own before you can do so.

---

Why do a `try...parse` around `DateTime.Parse`, when you could use [`DateTime.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1(v=vs.110).aspx)?

---

Twice you do `item[datesField].Cast<string>()`, and as it turns out, twice you then do `dates.Split('|').Select(n => n.Trim())`. That's a waste of effort, which to me suggest you should rethink the logic in `return new ExportsModel`. All of those `item[nameField].Cast<string>()` are pretty ugly and are repeated, so they should be moved to a method. I'd advice to convert `item` to an intermediate format first, before creating `ExportsModel`.

---

I'm not happy with this:

```
catch (Exception)
{
    return null;
}
```

I get your logic, but throwing an exception when not being able to parse a certain value is a bad pattern, IMHO.

---

Instead of `datesArray[i] + " " + timesArray[i] + "Uhr"`, use `string.Format`.

Same for `zip + " " + city + " " + street`.

---

This logic is repeated several times: `.AddHours(23).AddMinutes(59)`. Which suggests to me it should be moved to a method.

---

Avoid names like `timesArray` and `datesArray`, especially considering neither of them is an `Array`, they're `List<T>`.

Why is `a` assigned? It isn't used anywhere.

`test` as a variable name?

---

Are you certain that `GetCoordinates` isn't causing endless loops?

---

There are more issues with your code, but I'd advice you to apply these recommendations and any others you might receive, and post the result as a new question.