# Excel-to-JSON parser 2

Tags: c#, json, excel

After [first code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/122358/15199) I have fixed the found issues. Could you please review my new refactored application?

**Main class (entry point)**

```
    static class MainClass
{
    private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MainClass));

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();

        Log.Info("this app converts XLS data to export.json");

        var settings = SettingsController.LoadSettings(@"settings.json");
        var result = Converter.ConvertExcelToJson(settings);
        File.WriteAllText(@"export.json", result);

        Log.Info("converting finished.");
    }
}
```

**Converter.cs**

```
   static class Converter
{
    private static GoogleGeocoder GoogleGeocoder { get; set; }

    private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Converter));

    public static string ConvertExcelToJson(SettingsModel settings)
    {
        try
        {
            GoogleGeocoder = new GoogleGeocoder(); // default api key used

            var nameField = GetSourceFieldNumber(settings, "Name");
            var datesField = GetSourceFieldNumber(settings, "Dates");
            var timesField = GetSourceFieldNumber(settings, "Times");
            var zipField = GetSourceFieldNumber(settings, "PostalCode");
            var cityField = GetSourceFieldNumber(settings, "City");
            var streetField = GetSourceFieldNumber(settings, "Street");

            var book = new LinqToExcel.ExcelQueryFactory(settings.FileName);

            var worksheetName = book.GetWorksheetNames().FirstOrDefault();
            if (worksheetName == null)
                throw new Exception("Cannot find any worksheet");

            Log.Info("start converting, please wait...");

            ConsoleSpiner consoleSpiner = new ConsoleSpiner();

            var test = book
                .WorksheetRange(settings.CellToStart, settings.CellToEnd, worksheetName)
                .AsEnumerable()
                .Select(item =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        return new ExportsModel
                        {
                            Name = GetFiledValue(item, nameField),
                            ActionDates = GetActionDatesArray(GetFiledValue(item, datesField), GetFiledValue(item, timesField)),
                            City = GetFiledValue(item, cityField),
                            Geocode = GetCoordinates(GetFiledValue(item, zipField), GetFiledValue(item, cityField), GetFiledValue(item, streetField), consoleSpiner),
                            Street = GetFiledValue(item, streetField),
                            PostalCode = GetFiledValue(item, zipField),
                            LastDate = GetLastDate(GetFiledValue(item, datesField))
                        };
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Log.Error("Cannot convert the row. Don't stop the application. Other rows will be converted.", ex);
                        return null;
                    }
                })
                .Where(obj => obj != null)
                .ToJSON();

            return test;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error("Cannot convert data. Please check if all settings are correct", ex);
            return "";
        }
    }

    private static string GetFiledValue(Row item, int nameField)
    {
        return item[nameField].Cast<string>();
    }

    private static int GetSourceFieldNumber(SettingsModel settings, string destinationFieldName)
    {
        return settings.FieldsMapping.Single(n => n.DestinationFieldName.Equals(destinationFieldName)).SourceFieldNumber;
    }

    private static DateTime? GetLastDate(string dates)
    {

        DateTime lastDate;
        if (DateTime.TryParse(dates.Split('|').Select(n => n.Trim()).LastOrDefault(), out lastDate))
        {
            return lastDate.SetEndOfTheDay();
        }

        throw new Exception("The shop will not be added to list. Cannot parse last date field.Value of the field: " + dates);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<ActionDate> GetActionDatesArray(string dates, string times)
    {
        List<string> timesArray;
        List<string> datesArray;

        try
        {
            timesArray = times.Split('|').Select(n => n.Trim()).ToList();
            datesArray = dates.Split('|').Select(n => n.Trim()).ToList();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(string.Format("The shop will not be added to list. Cannot parse date or time field. Values needed to be parsed: dates={0}, times={1}", dates, times), ex);

        }

        for (var i = 0; i < datesArray.Count(); i++)
        {
            DateTime date;
            yield return new ActionDate()
            {
                Label = string.Format("{0} {1} Uhr", datesArray[i], timesArray[i]),
                Date = DateTime.TryParse(datesArray[i], out date) ? date.SetEndOfTheDay() : (DateTime?)null
            };
        }
    }

    private static Geocode GetCoordinates(string zip, string city, string street, ConsoleSpiner consoleSpiner)
    {
        try
        {

            IEnumerable<Address> addresses;
            try
            {
                addresses = GoogleGeocoder.Geocode(String.Format("{0} {1} {2}",zip, city, street)).ToList();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // try one more time
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                addresses = GoogleGeocoder.Geocode(String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", zip, city, street)).ToList();
            }

            consoleSpiner.Turn();

            return new Geocode()
            {
                Lat = addresses.First().Coordinates.Latitude,
                Lon = addresses.First().Coordinates.Longitude
            };

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(string.Format("The shop will not be added to list. The following data cannot be geocoded: ({0}-{1}-{2})", zip, city, street), ex);
        }
    }
}
```

**SettingsController.cs**

```
    static class SettingsController
{
    private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(SettingsController));

    public static SettingsModel LoadSettings(string settingsFileName)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!File.Exists(settingsFileName))
            {
                CreateSettingsFile(settingsFileName);
            }

            var settings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SettingsModel>(File.ReadAllText(settingsFileName));

            Log.Info("reading settings finished");

            return settings;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error("Cannot open/read settings file. Please check if all settings are correct", ex);
            Environment.Exit(0);
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static void CreateSettingsFile(string settingsFileName)
    {
        Log.Info("settings file was not found...");
        File.WriteAllText(settingsFileName, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new SettingsModel(true), Formatting.Indented));
        Log.Info("settings file was created, please edit it and start the programm again...");
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
}
```

**ExtensionMethods.cs**

```
    public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static DateTime SetEndOfTheDay(this DateTime dateTime)
    {
        return dateTime.AddHours(23).AddMinutes(59);
    }
}
```

**SettingsModel.cs**

```
  public class SettingsModel
{
    public SettingsModel(bool addDefaultValues=false)
    {
        if (addDefaultValues)
        {
            FieldsMapping = new List<Field>()
            {
                new Field() { DestinationFieldName = "Name",SourceFieldNumber = 6},
                new Field() { DestinationFieldName = "Dates",SourceFieldNumber = 12},
                new Field() { DestinationFieldName = "Times",SourceFieldNumber = 13},
                new Field() { DestinationFieldName = "PostalCode",SourceFieldNumber = 8},
                new Field() { DestinationFieldName = "City",SourceFieldNumber = 9},
                new Field() { DestinationFieldName = "Street",SourceFieldNumber = 7}
            };

            FileName = "source.xls";
            CellToStart = "A4";
            CellToEnd = "N133";

        }
    }

    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string CellToStart { get; set; }
    public string CellToEnd { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Field> FieldsMapping { get; set; }
}

public class Field
{
    public string DestinationFieldName { get; set; }
    public int SourceFieldNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't look bad now but I've spotted a few things that I still would change.

**Converter**

*.ConvertExcelToJson*

This method is expected to return a `string` but it doesn't do it if an exception occurs. This is rather an unexpected behaviour. From a method like this I would expect it to throw an exception if something went wrong or have a different signature like this one:

```
public static bool TryConvertExcelToJson(SettingsModel settings, out string result)
```

This clearly shows that it won't fail *whatsoever*.

---

*GetFiledValue* & *GetActionDatesArray* etc

They should all be private members of the `ExportsModel` whose constructor should be passed the `item`.

---

**SettingsController**

*CreateSettingsFile*

> ```
> Environment.Exit(0);
> ```

Putting this in that method is a very bad idea. I'd be really surprised if my application exited when I called this API.

If you still want to keep it there then consider naming the method `CreateSettingsFileAndExit` which would prevent such surprises.

---

**ExtensionMethods**

*SetEndOfTheDay*

This method does not *set-end-for-the-day*. It adds hours and minutes. What if the current time isn't exactly midnight? The end of they would be invalid. You should calculate the offsets or create an entirely new instance.

---

**SettingsModel**

Instead of having a constructor with a parameter I suggest keeping it clear and creating a new property

```
public static Default => new SettingsModel { ... }
```

and let it create a default model.